# How do I connect to a pool?

Tags: mining-pools, vps

I am using Putty via a VPS.  I have my wallet set up and can mine using start_mining.  I know how to access my wallet using ./monero-wallet-cli.  What I don't know is the command to use to connect to one of the pools out there.  Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Are you trying to mine directly from monero-wallet-cli? It is not possible to pool mine this way. You will need to use other software. See https://www.reddit.com/r/MoneroMining/wiki/index/linux-pool

Comment: So I am connected to the daemon ./monerod.  Now how do I join a pool?

Comment: What is the command if for instance, the pool is monerol.com?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to join a specific pool for example monerol.com, you can go to its getting started page which is http://monerol.com/#getting_started

As you can see there are many ways to connect to the pool just select the mining app of your choice. Normally, a VPS does not have GPU so select the one that support CPU mining. For example  you can use minerd like this

```
minerd -a cryptonight -o stratum+tcp://monerol.com:3333 -u YOUR_WALLET_ADDRESS -p x
```

You can install minerd by downloading and compiling it. The source is at https://github.com/wolf9466/cpuminer-multi

Edit: Another miner which is good is called xmr-stak-cpu you can get its source code here https://github.com/fireice-uk/xmr-stak-cpu

Hope this helps.

Comment: Don't I need a .tar file to use with Linux commands?

Comment: You can get the tar file by downloading it in the github link I posted. e.g. > get clone https://github.com/fireice-uk/xmr-stak-cpu.git or  > wget https://github.com/fireice-uk/xmr-stak-cpu/archive/master.zip (its a zip file)

Comment: I guess I will have to concede I am out of my element.  That is frustrating though as I have taught myself some aspects of Linux in the last couple of months.  I created a wallet, connected/Synced to the daemon and was able to start mining.  Unfortunately, I am mining solo which doesn't appear too promising.  I also created an account on minergate and am mining there through a pool.  What sucks is I signed up for a VPS, worked through all these Linux commands and just can't quite bring it all together.  Thank you for your help...

Comment: what kind of linux are you using?  I can edit my answer and put the exact step by step command on how to install the miner.  You can chat with us so it is easier. Try joining a small pool for example https://supportxmr.com . There is a chat on the lower left.

Comment: That link will not open.  Let me tell how I started, I signed up for a VPS using intersever.  I followed instructions here, https://www.reddit.com/r/Monero/comments/4z9wi0/guide_how_to_setup_a_monero_node_on_linux_via/ to create a wallet and connect to dameon.

Comment: I should add that I used Putty to create wallet and connect to daemon.  This was trial and error as I had never used Linux before so all new to me.  That is basically where I am.  I can log in as root to my VPS and connect to daemon, use wallet-cli to start/stop mining but that is as far as I have gotten.

Comment: Basically, I am paying a monthly fee for a VPS so that I can use their resources as opposed to my PC's to mine and store blockchain.  Unfortunately, I am solo mining and need to join a pool.

Comment: VPS probably is not the way to go if you want to mine, unless it is free. In addition you can create a wallet on your computer using the GUI so it is easier. If you really want to mine I can still help you with that. I will update the answer above with the exact step on installing a miner.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/55939/discussion-between-aarongary2002-and-gundamlancer).